# Summation of values in the same column in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to sum the values in the same column. I have tried with cross join and it does work for me but I dont want the result should be repeated values

What I have:- 
table:-

```
|key|year|value|
----------------
|sam|2013| 30   |
-----------------
|sam|2014| 50   |
-----------------
|sam|2015| 70   |
-----------------
|sam|2016| 90   |
-----------------
|Jam|2013| 0   |
-----------------
|Jam|2014| 10   |
-----------------
|Jam|2015| 0   |
-----------------
|Jam|2016| 20   |
-----------------
```

Query:-

```
SELECT (t1.value + t2.value) AS total
FROM table t1 CROSS JOIN table t2
WHERE t1.year = t2.year AND t1.key  <> t2.key;
```

Output for this Query:-

```
|total|
-----
|30|
-----
|60|
-----
|70|
-----
|110|
-----
|30|
-----
|60|
-----
|70|
-----
|110|
-----
```

But what I want is:-

```
|total|
-----
|30|
-----
|60|
-----
|70|
-----
|110|
-----
```

Can someone tell me what modification should I do to get this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want aggregation:

```
SELECT sum(value) as total
FROM table t1
GROUP BY year
ORDER BY year;
```

Comment: yes, but sequence is changing here, so what I am getting now is 2013,2016 so its not in order. If I used Order By year then it works but  I want only one col which is total

Comment: @NoviceProgrammer . . . It seems silly to me to just have a bunch of numbers without the year, but you can remove `year` from the `select` and include it in the `order by`.